# segue text on button with action (swift3)

Tags: ios, button, text, swift3, segue

I would like the user to hit the button add 1. Which then will display in the middle of the green box. So the user hits a button and the number one is displayed in the middle of the green box. This is not a counter so its just one. Think of it as a score card. The green box is referenced as score display.

[image]

```
 import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var scoreDisplay: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

}


@IBAction func add1(_ sender: Any) {


}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you wish to hide and show some views depending upon some user behaviour.

As of Swift 3, please take a look at the `isHidden` property of any UIView. You must have some `@IBOutlets` for your buttons, not only `@IBActions`.

A possible solution for you (write this in your `add1` function):

```
scoreDisplay.setTitle("1", for: .normal)
scoreDisplay.isHidden = false
```

Of course, do not forget to firstly set the `scoreDisplay` as hidden in the Interface Builder.